# Can Mysql interact with Elasticsearch To Find Match?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I have a wordpress website with mysql database of real estate properties listed for sale and an elasticsearch database of addresses I have curated.

Can the mysql query the elasticsearch database to find if there is a matching address then send back to wordpress to move the property into a "xyz" category?

If not does anyone know a way for this type of process to happen?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way MySQL can interact directly with ElasticSearch.

Typically you would develop code to interact with both ElasticSearch and MySQL in turn. This would be done with two separate queries. The first to query ElasticSearch to find a matching address, and then a second query against MySQL, using the information returned by the first query as a parameter for the MySQL query.

WordPress in this context is a client application for both MySQL and ElasticSearch. But each has its own protocol and connector. MySQL and ElasticSearch don't share data or queries.

---

Update: I found a way to use an ElasticSearch data source via MySQL's FEDERATED engine through a proxy that translates MySQL's protocol into ODBC to the ElasticSearch node. This is probably way too complex for your needs, but it is possible. See https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/elasticsearch-odbc-mysql-federated-tables.rst

By analogy, this is like asking "can I drive my car while making my car drive another car?" Yes, you can — just weld your car's steering rods to some long metal struts that operate the hands of a puppet version of you sitting in the other car.

I don't recommend it.